# Android Navigation Bar with Tool Bar overlap with Actual Toolbar

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

I m using Android Navigation Drawer, I have two screens, i copy pasted the navigation and changed bar, content page only, However for Page 1 everything is fine and for Page 2 (highlighted in red) is apperaing as extra.

Kindly please help

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:context="com.ntu.mobile.proj.docsearch.DocSearchActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/doc_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <include layout="@layout/content_docsearch" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_doc_search);

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.doc_spinner);

    Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    userName = extras.getString("userName");
    userId = extras.getInt("userId");

    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
            R.array.specialist_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_doc_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
            this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.setDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_doc_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    View header = navigationView.getHeaderView(0);

    userNameTxt = (TextView) header.findViewById(R.id.profile_name);
    userNameTxt.setText(userName);

    txt_search_docname = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_search_docname);
    txt_search_pincode = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txt_search_pincode);

}

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
```

[image: Highlighted in Red has issue]

Comment: can you post the activity onCreate method and what Theme are you extending ?

Comment: have posted code above, Thank you